# FreeRTOS find task waiting address

Tags: freertos

I have FreeRTOS project with 4 tasks. In some cases the device stops responding. When Break the MCU (stm32f4), in most cases it is in task switching subroutines (`tasks.c`) and goes to `vApplicationIdleHook`. How to find the address of main task at which it is stopeed?

Edit: I have `tskTCB` structure of interesting task. Is there a chance to find the return address for that task when I break execution in `vApplicationIdleHook` for example? It seems first member `pxTopOfStack` may help, but it points to unused memory...

Comment: What have you done to debug this? As a minimum have you followed the "[my application does not run, what could be wrong](http://www.freertos.org/FAQHelp.html)" FAQ item? Your post is not clear. You say the device is in the task switching sub-routine and goes to vApplicationIdleHook(), but vApplicationIdleHook() is called by the idle task - which is an executing task - it is not called by the task switching sub-routine. There is another hook function called vApplicationTickHook() that IS called by the task-switching sub-routine - are you sure it is not vApplicationTickHook() that is called? See

Comment: The application is running. But in some cases the main task seems hanging and I want to find the point of this. `vApplicationTickHook()` is called regularly as well as `vApplicationIdleHook()` (even when main task is hanging). I mentioned task switching subroutine because when I click "Break" in the IDE (Rowley Crossworks) most times it is stopped in such subroutine. Probably all tasks are blocked/waiting and FreeRTOS verifies whether they are still blocked and calls `vApplicationIdleHook`. My question is: when I break execution, what structure to see to find the return address in main task.